# D.I.Y. Pour Over Coffee Maker

Tags: pour-over

I have a friend that wants to try a pour over coffee but she doesn't know if she wants to invest in another coffee maker.

***question***: Do you think you could just use your standard drip coffee maker to hold your grounds and use a kettle to pour water over the grounds and get the same results?

Answer (score 4):

1. It should work since there is no magic involved in the pour over coffee maker. The only problem could be the pressure from the wet coffee on the 'arm' holding the coffee since it was never made to keep the coffee in midair.
2. It wouldn't be expensive to get only the coffee dripper ( I got a plastic one for 2 euro, fancier porcelain once come for 10 euro as far as I know). With them, you apply the same principle you mentioned. Boil water, pour a little on the coffee to let it soak, wait 1 minute, slowly pour the rest of the water on the ground ( be careful not to push the coffee away with the water)
3. Trough the result might differ due to the plastic, which could give a little different taste.

Answer (score 1):

That would work just fine. Campers make do with all sorts of kludges. All one needs to make drip coffee is coffee, hot water, a filter, and some ingenuity.

I go backwoods camping. I take a metal drip filter, place it on a mug, add coffee, pour in hot water and voila: I have my morning coffee.  While camping I have to make certain that the filter doesn't tip over and I lose my precious brew.

The reason to buy something special are aesthetics and functionality. At home you want to be to pour and walk away.